# Multiple where clauses in Querybase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I've been trying out [Querybase](https://github.com/davideast/Querybase) together with Firebase, but I am having some problems querying more then one variable. Lets say I have the following JSON structure:

```
{
    "Users": {
        "-Xtbhibiwd7": {
            "address" : "test200",
            "firstname" : "Joe",
            "lastname" : "Doe",
            "city" : "New York" 
         },
        "-bui379828": {
            "address" : "testRoad",
            "firstname" : "Peter",
            "lastname" : "Doe",
            "city" : "New York" 
         }
     }    
}
```

Now, I would like to get those Users with the 'lastname' : 'Doe' and 'city' : 'New York' and wrote the following code:

```
const firebaseRef = firebase.database().ref().child('users')
const querybaseRef = querybase.ref(firebaseRef, ['lastname', 'city'); 
        querybaseRef.where({
            lastname: 'Doe',
            city: 'New York'
        });

querybaseRef('value', snap => console.log('Received:', snap.val()));
```

The following query return 'null'. If I remove one of the variables in the where clause (does not matter which one), the correct result i retrieved for that where clause. For instance if removing last name will return all nodes containing the city New York.

[Link to JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/gobetas/edit?html,console)

Comment: If you create a plnkr or jsbin I'll take a look and debug it.

Comment: I've added a link to JS bin in the post. Now i get the following error: Uncaught TypeError: b.replace is not a function. I remember i got this error once before, but was able to solve it, without really knowing how and why. And therfore not able to create the original problem again, but would be nice to know what creates this error. In advantage: thanks!